# using glmer for nested data

Tags: r, nested, lme4

I have data on the diversity of pathogens infecting a particular host species across latitudes. The design involved collecting 20 individuals at 3 sites within 4 locations of different latitudes, therefore I have 20 individuals, nested within 3 sites, nested within 4 locations.

Given that my pathogen diversity data is count data with many zeros, which is why I have been exploring using using a GLMM with the `lme4::glmer` command in R to analyze the data. For the analysis I want to treat latitude as a numeric fixed factor and site as a random factor nested with location.

For my full model I have set up my command as follows:

```
glmer(pathogen.richness~latitude+(site|location),data=my.data,
      family="poisson")
```

Is this the correct syntax for what I described?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

You probably want

```
glmer(pathogen.richness~latitude+(1|location/site),
     data=my.data,family="poisson")
```

However, you're probably going to run into problems trying to fit a random effect of location to only 4 locations, so you may prefer

```
glmer(pathogen.richness~latitude+location+(1|location:site),
     data=my.data,family="poisson")
```

(even though location is *conceptually* a random effect, it may be more practical to fit it as a fixed effect).

Don't forget to check for overdispersion; one way to handle this is to add an observation-level random effect:

```
transform(my.data,obs=factor(seq(nrow(mydata)))
update(prev_model,.~.+(1|obs))
```

See the [GLMM FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html) and  http://glmm.wdfiles.com/local--files/examples/Banta_2011_part1.pdf for more information.